# Trying to dynamically change part of a function call

Tags: python-3.x

I might be (probably am) using the wrong terminology for some of this, but here's what I'm trying to do.

This is the current code:

```
with open('matchup' + MatchupStr_Test + '_' + HomeAway[MatchupNum_Test] + 'team_name_NewTest.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]].home_team.team_name))
```

I am attempting to take the word **home** from the second line (**.home_team.team_name**) and having it dynamically change so the word home would change depending on an array.

Here's what I thought would work, but doesn't.

```
with open('matchup' + MatchupStr_Test + '_' + HomeAway[MatchupNum_Test] + 'team_name_NewTest.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]].[HomeAway[MatchupNum_Test]]_team.team_name))
```

Absolute beginner here, so sorry if I'm wording this in a confusing way.  Just trying to have some fun on a Raspbi I wasn't currently using, so it doesn't have to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), which should work for this. The way `getattr` works is that it dynamically retrieves a property of an object using the name of the property.

For example:

```
team_name = HomeAway[MatchupNum_Test]

with open(f'matchup{MatchupStr_Test}_{team_name}team_name_NewTest.txt', 'w') as f:
  opposing_team = getattr(box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]], f'{team_name}_team')
  f.write(str(opposing_team.team_name))
```

In the above, we dynamically retrieve the attribute `f'{team_name}_team'` from the object `box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]]`.

So if `team_name` was `"home"` for example, then `getattr(box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]], f'{team_name}_team')` will be equivalent to `box_scores[MatchupNum[MatchupNum_Test]].home_team`

---

The `f` in front of the strings has nothing to do with the `f` representing the file. They are called [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and are a much nicer way of combining strings, than using `+`.